# In unit tests User.Identity is being set to my windows user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm unit testing my WebAPI using HttpClient and self hosted api. I have a custom MessageHandler setting principal based on API key sent by the client. My controller is protected with [Authorize] attribute, but my test call gets in, because User.Identity is filled with my windows username. How can I make sure user isn't set when making an HttpClient call from my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `MessageHandler` should set the User to null if the API key is not provided or invalid:

```
IPrincipal principal = null;

if (IsValidApiKey(someKey))
{
    // The provided API key is valid => we populate the principal
    principal = ...
}

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how/why is it being set to my windows user?

Comment: Because you are using self-hosting and the API automatically impersonates the user that is executing it. When you host in IIS, it's different because the API is taking the identity of ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there a way to change this configuration?

Comment: If you don't want to modify the code of the service you could write another custom handler specifically for the unit test which is setting the principal to null and register it in your self-host.